# How to modify netcdf file with PyNCO ncap2?

Tags: python, netcdf, nco, pynco

I'm trying to use NCO command ncap2 in python script for changing time units in the climatology NetCDF-file:

```
from nco import Nco
nco = Nco()
nco.ncap2(input='in.nc', output='out.nc', options =['-s', '\\"time@units=\\"days since 00-12-30 00:00:00\\"\\"'])
```

However, this gives me an error:

> C:\Users\test\Miniconda3\envs\download\Library\bin\ncap2 -s
>   "time@units="days since 00-12-30 00:00:00"" --output=out.nc in.nc
>   <<< Inputs: out.nc b'' Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\test\workspace\GFSdownload\src\nc_info.py", line 13, in
>    nco.ncap2(input='in.nc', output='out.nc', options =['-s',
>   '\"time@units=\"days since 00-12-30 00:00:00\"\"']) File
>   "C:\Users\test\Miniconda3\envs\download\lib\site-packages\nco\nco.py",
>   line 342, in get raise NCOException(**retvals) nco.nco.NCOException:
>   (returncode:1) b''

While using ncap2 directly from command line works good:

```
ncap2 -s "time@units=\"days since 00-12-30 00:00:00\"" in.nc out.nc
```

Is there a workaround for this? I'm writing my main code in python, so I'd like to use pynco everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem with ncap2 is but you could instead try ncatted (that rhymes!)

Comment: upvote but not for your poetry Charlie, don't give up the day job ;-)